# sparse and dense in hyperion

Tags: oracle11g, hyperion, essbase

I am new to Hyperion Essbase.

What is the difference between a SPARSE and DENSE Dimension? Is there any documentation that could help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

The Essbase [Database Administrator's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/esb_dbag/frameset.htm?launch.html) contains all the information you need to know about `SPARSE` versus `DENSE` dimensions in the Essbase multidimensional database.

From the guide:

> Most multidimensional databases are inherently sparse; they lack data
>   values for the majority of member combinations. A sparse dimension is
>   one with a low percentage of available data positions filled.

When you think of the essbase cube, think of your `DENSE` dimensions as the axis of the cube (X, Y, Z). There are always data points (even if they're empty) for all intersections of (X, Y, Z).

Think of your `SPARSE` dimensions as a group of these cubes, which only exist if there is data existing for that value of the sparse dimension.

Data is only stored on disk for a SPARSE dimension's value when that data actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Go through this link, it covers how the Hyperion works and it will cater your problem too.

```
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_dbag/frameset.htm?dinconc.htm
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Essbase, there are two type of database.
1. ASO
2. BSO

For BSO, Essbase divided dimension into two type(dense and sparse)
Dense dimension : those who have high availability of data.
Sparse dimension: those have less availability of data.

In Essbase, 
*data store in data block. 
*dense member decide the size of data block.
*sparse member decide the location of the data block(.ind).